# How does RollingFileAppender work with log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I'm use to `RollingFileAppender` on normal log4j. Now I'm switching to `log4j2`, and cannot get the appender to work.

The `File` appender below works as expected. But the logging file for `RollingFile` is never created. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="FILE" fileName="c:/logs.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c: %m%n" />
        </File>

        <RollingFile name="ROLLING" fileName="c:/logsroll.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c: %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="0.001 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE" />
            <AppenderRef ref="ROLLING" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `RollingFile` tag is missing a `filePattern` attribute.

```
<RollingFile name="ROLLING" 
             fileName="c:/logsroll.log"
             filePattern="c:/logsroll-%i.log">
```

Comment: Correct. You need the filePattern attribute so that the rollover mechanism knows how to rename the old log files (and potentially zip them).

Comment: Additionally, if you add attribute `status="trace"` to the top `<Configuration>` element (`<Configuration status="trace">`), log4j2 debug info will be printed to the console to help you troubleshoot any configuration issues.

Comment: Any guess how can I use this attribute in a configuration file and not in a XML config?

Comment: What exactly means `configuration file` if it not means `XML config`? ([See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235021/log4j2-on-android/28453604#28453604) for an approach for a configuration without configuration file.)

Comment: so the parent folder (c:/ in here) need to be specified twice? both in fileName and filePattern? what if they are specified different?

Comment: Why both `fileName` and `filePattern`!? I know the documentation lists both.

Answer (score 8):

I used log4j2 version 2.0, in some cases it throws error if you do not set any date in file pattern, in this case you can use some thing like below:

```
      <RollingFile name="MyFile" fileName="d:/log/bsi/admin/total/totalLog.log"
            filePattern="d:/log/totalLog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2000"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

Comment: "some cases" is exactly when you are using <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />

Comment: In my case the property `filePattern` was written in lowercase