# Log4j2 Causing Fatal Exception in Android Project

Tags: android, gradle, log4j2

Moving a Java project with Maven over to an Android project with Gradle in IntelliJ and everything made the transition smoothly except for Log4j2.

This error message fires whenever the program tries to create a Logger:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil$PrivateSecurityManager.getCallerClass(ReflectionUtil.java:301)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil.getCallerClass(ReflectionUtil.java:214)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.util.ReflectionUtil.getCallerClass(ReflectionUtil.java:193)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:72)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:195)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:160)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:492)
at com.company.sample.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:18)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Here's the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.sample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/Log4j2Plugins.dat'
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version:'2.3'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version:'2.3'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.13'
    compile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version:'2.11.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I was initially using SLF4J with Log4j2, but refactored to straight Log4j2 while troubleshooting. When I use newer versions of Log4j2 I start getting:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
```

I updated to a newer version of Gradle and the Gradle plugin, but that gave similar task fails but for the 'Desugar' process.

Totally removing any reference to Log4j2 and using no logging or logging with slf4j-simple the program runs fine.

I don't know if this is related, but it seems like the program is not finding the log4j2.xml file. It was initially in the '/src/main/resources/' folder, but I've renamed it and placed it in different folders along the class path and the errors are always the same. I've also used "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=file:/mypath/.../log4j2.xml" on the Gradle VM Options to try to force the program to read the configuration with the same results.

Any help you can offer is appreciated.

Comment: Please ask on the Log4j2 mailing list or raise a Log4j2 JIRA ticket. Actually as of 2.10 Log4j2 has issues with Android and the Log4j2 community is looking for people willing to help out with this.

Comment: Thanks Remko. I put in a ticket. I also found a question on here this morning that has the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235021/log4j2-on-android  
I'll attempt their solution when I get back on my dev machine.