# Convert log4j 1.x to log4j 2.x custom layout appender

Tags: log4j2

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${catalina.base}/logs/server.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
        <layout class="com.mayank.base.logging.CustomPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE}#%X{requestId} %R %-5p [%c{1}] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

I am facing trouble converting it to log4j 2. How i can addmy custom pattern layout.

Comment: More detail about what you have tried and why it's not working would make this question easier to understand

Answer (score 0):

The `<RollingFile>` tag should be present.

Here are couple of samples -

```
<RollingFile name="ROLLING" 
             fileName="f:/my_dir/logsroll.log"
             filePattern="f:/my_dir/logsroll-%i.log">
```

OR

```
<RollingFile name="MyFile" fileName="d:/log/bsi/admin/total/totalLog.log"
            filePattern="d:/log/totalLog-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2000"/>
        </RollingFile>
```

Refer[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975292/how-does-rollingfileappender-work-with-log4j2) for more.

Comment: I am facing problem in adding my customPatternLayout

Comment: And this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24205093/how-to-create-a-custom-appender-in-log4j2

Comment: I already checked it. Looking for some alternative. My old custom layout is in base library used across organization dont wannna change it.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement your CustomPatternLayout as a Layout plugin. You have a code example on ([layout plugins manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Layouts)).

In very general you should :

- Implement the plugin class with proper annotations on the constructor
- Implement the plugin factory method
- Implement the desired formatting
- Mention in log4j configuration your plugins package:

  ```
  <Configuration packages="com.mayank.base.logging">
  ```
- Use in the configuration the name of your plugin class

You can see explanations and examples of plugins implementation on this blog [post1](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/09/nullappender-implementation-for-log4j2.html), [post2](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/04/extending-log4j2-format-with-plugins.html), [post3](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/04/use-log4j2-filter-plugin-4-separate-errors-log.html). There is no layout plugin example, but the technique is very similar.