# Log4j2 subAppend substitute

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I want to write custom appenders for consoleAppender and RollingFileAppender to add another few custom fields to the log. With Log4j1 it was possible with subAppend() method. Log4j2 does not provide this method. How can I implement this in Log4j2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In log4j2, 
you would create a plugin for this.
The manual has an explanation with an example for a custom appender here:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Appenders

on plugins:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html

If you are looking for 
RollingFileAppender work with log4j2

[How does RollingFileAppender work with log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20975292/6032482)